# Angular 7 bootstrap doesn't load designs

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Why does bootstrap doesn't load the design properly in my angular 7

I am using Visual studio code
i added a new component and `login`
 and i executed the query below

```
npm install bootstrap
npm install popper.js
npm install jquery
```

Then i modified the `angular.json` the style and script array

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            ],
```

But why does the web browser doesn't load the design of the form?

Here is the code

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Which i get from here `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/`

Did i missed to modify another file in order for the bootstrap 4 to be loaded properly in angular 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line to your style.css

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

hope it helps

Comment: wow it worked. what's the difference with the one that i did. Then if it is needed. Why do i need to modify the content of the angular.json file?

Comment: well, As far as I know you don't need to add  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" to your angular.json file

Comment: Then where do i put the script? if that is not needed? Thank you

Comment: I already marked as answer. But if i need the script. Where do i need to put that? or how do i reference it?

Comment: Thanks, you can add the script to your index.html using  script tag